# GetInstance<T>()' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly

Tags: c#, .net, generics, activator

I have created a dynamic method to create an instance of different type, but not sure why it is giving above mentioned error at compile time, also do I have to again cast the return value to the specified type?

```
 internal static T GetInstance<T>()
    {
        dynamic obj = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T));
        return obj;
    }

    private Foo f = GetInstance<Foo>();
```

Comment: Why the `dynamic`? You probably just need `return (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T));` But where's the error coming from - your function? The line that's calling it?

Comment: Good question, actually I have to set other properties too

Comment: And it is giving error at compile time

Comment: The code as posted will not produce that error. Please post your actual code. That error typically occurs when you have a method of `T GetInstance<T>(T x)` and call it with `GetInstance(y)` (notice no `<X>` on the call), and the compiler is unable to infer what type `y` refers to.

Comment: The code you have, even though a few bits could be better (no need for `dynamic`, etc) - compiles and runs fine. I don't think you've shown us the code that actually raises this compiler message.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why don't you just use what MSDN recommends, which is the following:

```
internal static T GetInstance<T>() where T:new()
{
    return new T();
}
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0hcyx2kd.aspx

EDIT:

Though, I don't understand why you even want to have this method?

Instead of calling `var x = GetInstance<Foo>();`, you could just do `var x = new Foo();` since Foo must have parameterless constructor if you want to call `GetInstance<T>()` with `Foo` as the type parameter ( or am I missing something? ).

Comment: Thanks Jaaco +1, but why Where T: new() ?

Comment: Faster and identical - CreateInstance can do dynamic parameters, but when you dont pass them in it cna not do it, then new works better than createisntance - stronger biding.

Comment: @BreakHead It's Jaakko :) If there wasn't "new()" constraint, you wouldn't be able to do "new T()". All that constraint does is that it guarantees that 'T' has a parameterless constructor.

Comment: YOu also get a compiler not runtime error when the type can not be instanciated without parameter ;)

Comment: @BreakHead `where T:new()` is a constraint for `T` that defines that `T` must have a public default constructor. That can be checked by compiler. If you have that constraint you can use `new T()` that calls that public default consturctor.